# weak limit similiar to central limit theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I need to calclulate
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{S_i }{\sqrt{n}}$$
where $$ S_i=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ for i.i.d $X_1,X_2,...$ with Expectation 0 and variance 1. I know from the CLT that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i }{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to the Standard-Normal distribution. Note that I need to calculate the weak limit. What does that even mean?

Solved by [JGWang](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601463/calculation-problem-with-central-limit-theorem%22)

Comment: Please refer to "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601463/calculation-problem-with-central-limit-theorem".